# I am getting an error while installing android platform for Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Getting an error while installing for android platform in phonegap, have set npm config set proxy http://proxydomain:port/ and npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ also. Checked android path source in env variable. Kindly let me how can I resolve it. Thank you.

> C:\cordovaTest>cordova platforms add android
>
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1
>   TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:73:11)
>       at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
>       at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova
>   \node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tun
>   nel-agent\index.js:117:25)
>       at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\Program Files\nod
>   ejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
>   request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:184:41)
>       at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\n
>   ode_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunne
>   l-agent\index.js:80:8)
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
>       at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
>       at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
>       at Request.start (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\
>   cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:594:30)
>       at Request.end (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\co
>   rdova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:1186:28)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, i finally found a solution : downgrade nodejs to 0.10.29 version

and it's running now !

Comment: Fantastic Alex, that was awesome!!

Comment: worked with me also with the latest 0.10.38 nodejs version, also if you want to install more than node version , use this simple tool for windows https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, downgrading to node 0.10 fixes the issue. Alternatively you can do the following :

- download latest version of tunnel-agent [here](https://github.com/mikeal/tunnel-agent)
- and put it in the npm folder of your installed cordova-lib : `.\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent`

Source of information : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8662

Comment: It works. Thanks. I prefer this rather downgrade node.

Answer (score 2):

it worked for us: 0.10.38
instead of last version v0.12.2

direct link here:

> http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/x64/node-v0.10.38-x64.msi

it seems there is a bug in the tunnel-agent module for node.js, when building path it expect strings while a JS object is received.